# Genson deserialize a list of given types

Tags: java, genson

I'm writing a help function. `getList` will get serialized data from somewhere, and deserialize it.

getList always returns a List. Users will specify the type of the elements. The expected usage is like this:

```
List<Asset> l1 = getList("Asset"); //warning Unchecked assignment is fine
List<Store> l2 = getList("Store");
//or 
List<Asset> l1 = getList(Asset.class);
List<Store> l2 = getList(Store.class);
//or 
List<Asset> l1 = getList<Asset>();
List<Store> l2 = getList<Store>();
```

How would I fix the following implementation? It doesn't compile because className is a variable while List<> expects a class.

```
public static List getList(String className)
{
    Genson genson = new Genson();
    String data = ...
    List l= genson.deserialize(data, List<className>);
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    return l;
}
```

Comment: Genson seems to be a lesser used library and thus I doubt you'd find much help on it here. How about just passing `List.class`? If you need more information on the element type (i.e. use `className` you might need to pass something else (Jackson as `TypeRef` for this, no idea what Genson has).

Comment: There is a getting started guide for geson at http://genson.io/GettingStarted/. This has the following example for generic types: `List<Person> persons = genson.deserialize(json, new GenericType<List<Person>>(){});`

Comment: @Jack how would I make `Person` a variable that callers can pass in?

Answer (score 0):

There is a getting started guide for geson at http://genson.io/GettingStarted. This has the following example for generic types:

```
List<Person> persons = genson.deserialize(json, new GenericType<List<Person>>(){});
```

If you want to pass the type of the list elements to the method, you can introduce a type parameter:

```
public static <T> List<T> getList(String json, Class<T> clazz) {
    Genson genson = new Genson();
    List<T> list = genson.deserialize(json, new GenericType<List<T>>(){});
    return list;
}
```

An example for using the method would then look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> stringList = getList("[ \"element1\", \"element2\" ]", String.class);
    System.out.println(stringList);

    List<Integer> integerList = getList("[ 1, 2, 3 ]", Integer.class);
    System.out.println(integerList);
}
```

This will produce the following output:

```
[element1, element2]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: It does not work. I got List of HashMap instead of List of Person.